# Question on Theorem 5.1 from K.C Chang's book

Tags: analysis, orthogonal-polynomials, morse-theory

I have this theorem and in the first part of the proof , I don't understand why $d_z f(\theta_1+\theta_2)=\theta_1$ ?

> **Theorem $5.1$.** Suppose that $U$ is a neighborhood of $\theta$ in a Hilbert space $H$ and that $f\in C^2(U,\mathbb{R}^1)$. Assume that $\theta$ is the only critical point of $f$ and that $A=d^2f(\theta)$ with kernel $N$. If $0$ is either an isolated point of the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ or not in $\sigma(A)$, then there exist a ball $B_\delta$, and a $C^1$ mapping $h:B_\delta\cap N\to N^\perp$ such that
>   $$
> \tag{5.1}f\circ\phi(z+y)=\frac12(Az,z)+f(h(y)+y),\quad\forall x\in B_\delta,
> $$
>   where $y=P_Nx$, $z=P_{N^\perp}x$, and $P_N$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $N$.
>
> **Proof.** $1$. Decomposing the space $H$ into $N\oplus N^\perp$, we have
>   $$
> d_zf(\theta_1+\theta_2)=\theta_1\quad(\theta_1=P_{N^\perp}\theta, \theta_2=P_N\theta),
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> d_z^2f(\theta_1+\theta_2)=A|_{N^\perp}.
> $$
>   Because of the implicit function theorem, there is a function $h:B_\delta\cap N\to N^\perp$, $\delta\gt0$, such that
>   $$
> d_zf(y+h(y))=\theta_1
> $$
>   Let $u=z-h(y)$, and let
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> &F(u,y)=f(z+y)-f(h(y)+y)\tag{5.2}\\
> &\quad\qquad F_2(u)=\frac12(Au,u).\tag{5.3}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   Then we obtain
>   $$
> F(\theta_1,y)=0\\
> d_uF(\theta_1,y)=d_zf(h(y)+y)=\theta_1,\\
> d_u^2F(\theta_1,\theta_2)=d_z^2f(\theta)=A|_{N^\perp}.
> $$

Thank you.

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: Infinite dimensional Morse theory and multiple solution problems , K.C Chang

Comment: @MatthewConroy please i need help

Comment: I'm afraid this subject is not familiar to me.